# SKLearn pipeline with FeatureUnion works weird

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a dataset, where in one column I've got raw text data, and in others categories stored as texts. So kinda like this:

```
u_category | rawtext
cat1         This is a category
cat2         This is category 2
cat1         This again belongs to category 1
```

I'm building a pipeline that can 1) transform the category into integers via a `LabelEncoder` and 2) transform the data from the text with a tf-idf vectoriser 3) combine them via `FeatureUnion` and finally 4) learn to classify them with a `LinearSVC`.

This works fine when I'm fitting data. However, when I'm trying to get the score on a test dataset, I get the error that new values have been introduced into the `y` variable, even though when I check, the `y` values don't contain new values. It seems like the error is containing values from the `rawtext` column of the test set of values, and I can't figure out, why it keeps messing things up. To sum it up, I've got the same format of data for fitting AND testing, yet, when testing, the code seems to try to use data from X instead of y as the target class.

The full code with the helper functions and everything:

```
class MyLabelEncoder(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self):
        self.le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()

    def fit(self, x, y=None):
        return self.le.fit(x)

    def transform(self, x, y=None):
        return self.le.transform(x).reshape(-1,1)

    def fit_transform(self, x, y=None):
        self.fit(x)
        return self.transform(x)

class ItemSelector(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key

    def fit(self, x, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, data_dict):
        return data_dict[self.key]

df_resolved.u_category = df_resolved.u_category.fillna("")

pipeline = Pipeline([

    # Use FeatureUnion to combine the features from subject and body
    ('union', FeatureUnion(
        transformer_list=[
            # Pipeline for pulling features from the post's subject line
            ('rawtext', Pipeline([
                ('selector', ItemSelector(key='u_category')),
                ('labelenc', MyLabelEncoder()),
            ])),

            # Pipeline for standard bag-of-words model for body
            ('features', Pipeline([
                ('selector', ItemSelector(key='rawtext')),
                ('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer(max_df=0.5, min_df=1, 
                                          stop_words='english', 
                                          token_pattern=u'(?ui)\\b\\w*[a-z]{2,}\\w*\\b')),
            ])),
        ],

        # weight components in FeatureUnion
        transformer_weights={
            'rawtext': 1.0,
            'features': 1.0,
        },
    )),

    # Use a SVC classifier on the combined features
    ('linear_svc', LinearSVC(penalty="l2")),
])

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df_resolved[['u_category','caller_id.country','rawtext']], df_resolved['assignment_group.name'], test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

(It is largely based on [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/hetero_feature_union.html) tutorial with helper functions to solve some issues described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46054644/custom-featureunion-wont-work)).

Up until now, everything's A-OK. And then I try to do the blasphemy of:

```
print(pipeline.score(X_test, y_test))
```

And then it all goes wrong. Full stack trace:

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-80-c3e529f2bc17> in <module>()
----> 1 print(pipeline.score(X_test, y_test))

/Users/csanadpoda/Documents/Jupyter/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/metaestimators.py in <lambda>(*args, **kwargs)
     52 
     53         # lambda, but not partial, allows help() to work with update_wrapper
---> 54         out = lambda *args, **kwargs: self.fn(obj, *args, **kwargs)
     55         # update the docstring of the returned function
     56         update_wrapper(out, self.fn)

/Users/csanadpoda/Documents/Jupyter/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in score(self, X, y)
    502         for name, transform in self.steps[:-1]:
    503             if transform is not None:
--> 504                 Xt = transform.transform(Xt)
    505         return self.steps[-1][-1].score(Xt, y)
    506 

/Users/csanadpoda/Documents/Jupyter/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in transform(self, X)
    761         Xs = Parallel(n_jobs=self.n_jobs)(
    762             delayed(_transform_one)(trans, name, weight, X)
--> 763             for name, trans, weight in self._iter())
    764         if not Xs:
    765             # All transformers are None

/Users/csanadpoda/Documents/Jupyter/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py in __call__(self, iterable)
    756             # was dispatched. In particular this covers the edge
    757             # case of Parallel used with an exhausted iterator.
--> 758             while self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
    759                 self._iterating = True
    760             else:

/Users/csanadpoda/Documents/Jupyter/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py in dispatch_one_batch(self, iterator)
    606                 return False
    607             else:
--> 608                 self._dispatch(tasks)
    609                 return True
    610 

/Users/csanadpoda/Documents/Jupyter/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py in _dispatch(self, batch)
    569         dispatch_timestamp = time.time()
    570         cb = BatchCompletionCallBack(dispatch_timestamp, len(batch), self)
--> 571         job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
    572         self._jobs.append(job)
    573 

/Users/csanadpoda/Documents/Jupyter/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/_parallel_backends.py in apply_async(self, func, callback)
    107     def apply_async(self, func, callback=None):
    108         """Schedule a func to be run"""
--> 109         result = ImmediateResult(func)
    110         if callback:
    111             callback(result)

/Users/csanadpoda/Documents/Jupyter/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/_parallel_backends.py in __init__(self, batch)
    324         # Don't delay the application, to avoid keeping the input
    325         # arguments in memory
--> 326         self.results = batch()
    327 
    328     def get(self):

/Users/csanadpoda/Documents/Jupyter/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py in __call__(self)
    129 
    130     def __call__(self):
--> 131         return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    132 
    133     def __len__(self):

/Users/csanadpoda/Documents/Jupyter/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    129 
    130     def __call__(self):
--> 131         return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    132 
    133     def __len__(self):

/Users/csanadpoda/Documents/Jupyter/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in _transform_one(transformer, name, weight, X)
    565 
    566 def _transform_one(transformer, name, weight, X):
--> 567     res = transformer.transform(X)
    568     # if we have a weight for this transformer, multiply output
    569     if weight is None:

/Users/csanadpoda/Documents/Jupyter/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in _transform(self, X)
    443         for name, transform in self.steps:
    444             if transform is not None:
--> 445                 Xt = transform.transform(Xt)
    446         return Xt
    447 

<ipython-input-32-297ed049a40a> in transform(self, x, y)
      7 
      8     def transform(self, x, y=None):
----> 9         return self.le.transform(x).reshape(-1,1)
     10 
     11     def fit_transform(self, x, y=None):

/Users/csanadpoda/Documents/Jupyter/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/label.py in transform(self, y)
    151         if len(np.intersect1d(classes, self.classes_)) < len(classes):
    152             diff = np.setdiff1d(classes, self.classes_)
--> 153             raise ValueError("y contains new labels: %s" % str(diff))
    154         return np.searchsorted(self.classes_, y)
    155 

ValueError: y contains new labels: ['Account Access' 'Alert Generation' 'Appworx'
 'Capital EMEA (WCS BI Interfaces)' 'Client End - Calendar'
 'DB Connection Issues' ... ... 'Transferred Case' 'Unavailable/Error' 'User Admin' 'Windows 7' 'production scheduling']
```

This looks very much like data from the `rawtext` column of `X_test`, which is a pandas DataFrame, as opposed to the classes in `y_test`, in which all values start with the @ sign.

What am I messing up? How to tell the score of the LinearSVC model in this setup? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, thats because the LabelEncoder has encountered some new values in `u_category` in X_test which were not present in X_train.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have been careful when answering your previous question. To solve this, you can convert the data using LabelEncoder before you split into train and test and remove that from the pipeline altogether.

Comment: But still it will be upon you you to decide how to work this in real world scenario. Because in that, what you will do for unseen data?