# Transformers should implement fit() and transform()

Tags: scikit-learn

I'm not seeing why this block of Pipeline code from sklearn won't work...cna anyone else figure out why I'm getting the error:

```
TypeError: All intermediate steps should be transformers and implement fit and transform.

pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('features', FeatureUnion([
        ('plots', Pipeline([
            ('selector', movies_encoded['Plot']),
            ('count_vector', CountVectorizer(tokenizer=nltk.word_tokenize)),
            ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer())
        ])),
        ('genres', Pipeline([
            ('selector', movies_encoded['Rating_Encoded']),
            ('labeler', LabelEncoder())
        ]))
    ])),
    ('neural_network', MLPClassifier(alpha=0.01, hidden_layer_sizes=(100, 100, ), early_stopping=False, verbose=True))
])
```

All of the estimators DO have either transform() or fit_transform() methods. Argh. Thanks!

Comment: do you put a pipeline inside a pipeline ? can you add some data and the full code ?

Comment: Thanks! The data would come from the 4 variables for train_test_split(), and bellow the code block above I'd call pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train). But oddly, it's not working, as it's saying the fit() and transform() aren't applicable on my estimators, which they clearly are.

Comment: The error is in `movies_encoded`. You cannot simply put data columns inside the `Pipeline`. You will need to pass the data only in `fit()`. Check this example on how to select a single column from data: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/preprocessing/plot_function_transformer.html